# Why does this PHP function return the wrong result?

Tags: php

I wrote a user function to return the distance between two points on an x,y coordinate system.  The input params were `0,0,10,10`.

Here is the original code:

```
public static function dist2d($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2) {
   return sqrt((($x2 - $x1) * ($x2 - $x1)) + (($y2 - $y1) * ($y2 - $y1)));
}
```

This returns 110.

Here is the code that works:

```
public static function dist2d($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2) {
    $result = (($x2 - $x1) * ($x2 - $x1)) + (($y2 - $y1) * ($y2 - $y1));
    return sqrt($result);
}
```

This returns `14.1`.

I am new to PHP, what is going on here?

Comment: They both return the same for me. What version of PHP do you have and what's your environment?

Comment: That's really irrelevant. PHP has never had a bug adding, subtracting and multiplying integers in any version on any platform. The problem is not PHP, it's some code of his.

Comment: Mel, just for kicks, try copying first code snippet above (the one that you say returns 110), and pasting that into your PHP page. Don't retype it, copy and paste it from here. Karim79 reproduced the same return value (in an answer now deleted) by misplacing a set of parentheses (and by doing so, asking the function to evaluate `sqrt(100) + 100`, which correctly returns `110`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of these functions return 14.142135623731.

Comment: Not on my system  I am running apache, php, ubuntu and using the Yii framework.  I get 110 with the first syntax and 14.14,,,, with the second.

Comment: Then your code is not the same as above. If you remove one set of parentheses around the whole expression in your first function you would get 110. But not as is (correct).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about that? It's pretty strange because the two functions are identical.

I tried both of them in my environment (using cut & paste from your question) and both return 14.142135623731.

Answer (score 1):

It must be an oddity with your particular version of PHP, because mine works fine (5.3.3).

Answer (score 1):

You have probably made some kind of typo - both versions work for me correctly (please see http://codepad.org/1gFCTPfU as evidence).

Plus, if you are not describing static method of some class, you should replace `public static function dist2d(` with `function dist2d(`, otherwise you will get parse error as here: http://codepad.org/GkMfFqlo

Comment: It is part of a class definition.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Mel: Am I correct thinking the issue was a typo, or this was something else?